# Send Get to website with lua

Tags: lua, luasocket

i'm having a trouble with lua.

I need send a request to a website by GET and get the response from website.

Atm all i have is this:

```
local LuaSocket = require("socket")
client = LuaSocket.connect("example.com", 80)
client:send("GET /login.php?login=admin&pass=admin HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
while true do
  s, status, partial = client:receive('*a')
  print(s or partial)
  if status == "closed" then 
    break 
  end
end
client:close()
```

What should i do to get the response from server ?

I want to send some info to this website and get the result of page.

Any ideas ?

Comment: What does `print(s or partial)` return? If it is printing nil, then your connection was not established. Otherwise, `s` contains the response from the server (including header info).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the problem passing the header

```
local LuaSocket = require("socket")
client = LuaSocket.connect("example.com", 80)
client:send("GET /login.php?login=admin&pass=admin HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: example.com\r\n\r\n")
while true do
  s, status, partial = client:receive('*a')
  print(s or partial)
  if status == "closed" then 
    break 
  end
end
client:close()
```

Answer (score 8):

This probably won't work as `*a` will be reading until the connection is closed, but in this case the client doesn't know how much to read. What you need to do is to read line-by-line and parse the headers to find Content-Length and then after you see two line ends you read the specified number of bytes (as set in Content-Length).

Instead of doing it all yourself (reading and parsing headers, handling redirects, 100 continue, and all that), `socket.http` will take care of all that complexity for you. Try something like this:

```
local http = require("socket.http")
local body, code, headers, status = http.request("https://www.google.com")
print(code, status, #body)
```